# prove that $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ that has continuous partial derivative, then $f(A)$ is open for any open set $A \subset \mathbb R^2$

Tags: calculus

prove that $f:\mathbb R^2   \to \mathbb R^2$ that has continuous partial derivative, then $f(A)$ is open for any open set $A \subset \mathbb R^2$

I know that if $f(A)$ is open implies $f^{-1}(f(A))$ is open then we have a continuous function, but I'm not sure that the converse is true. I'm trying to find a counter example, but got no luck so far.

Comment: if I let $B=f(A)$ then isn't it $f^{-1}(B)=f^{-1}(f(A))=A$?

Comment: No it isn't, you only have $f^{-1}(f(A))\supseteq A$, consider $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$, $(x,y)\mapsto x$. If you want $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$, just take any $f$ which isn't injective.

Comment: oh, I see. thanks.

Comment: This seems related to the inverse function theorem, have you tried using it?

Comment: I did but it doesn't get anywhere, I've just talked to my professor, she told me that my instinct was right, that it's not true and I need an counter example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f(x,y):=(x,y^2)$. Then $f({\mathbb R}^2)$ is the closed upper half plane.

**Edit** upon comment: Note that $x$ takes arbitrary values in ${\mathbb R}$, and $y^2$ takes arbitrary values in ${\mathbb R}_{\geq0}$, independently of $x$. It follows that $f({\mathbb R}^2)={\mathbb R}\times{\mathbb R}_{\geq0}$, *vulgo*: the closed upper half plane.

Comment: can you explain a little bit why $f(\mathbb R^2)$ is closed upper half plane please?